# Unable to bind dynamically added Spring TextArea to Model Attribute using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

Its my first time so please ignore if I haven't phrase it properly. My target is to create a web page in which user could add/delete multiple text areas in a table and once the page is submitted the whole page should be inserted into the database.

Data Objects:

> **DigestSection.java**

```
public class DigestSection implements Transferable {
  private Long   digestSectionId;
  private String body;
  private String title;
}
```

> **DigestTemplate.java**

```
public class DigestTemplate implements Transferable {
  private String              description;
  private String              title;
  private List<DigestSection> section;
}
```

So `DigestTemplate` could have a `List` of `DigestSection`s which in my case is:

[Section Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrOvE.png)

In a digest if user clicks on a button to add a new section, actually this title and content editor is created for which I have created a form in which a table is created to hold all the sections as a row as below

```
<form:form id="digestForm" modelAttribute ="digesttemplate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table class="table" id="contentTable" >
    <tbody>
      <c:forEach items="${digesttemplate.section}" varStatus="sectionContent" var="sectionVR">
        <tr>
          <td class="control-label">
            <form:input path="section[${sectionContent.index}].title" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <form:textarea id="html-body${sectionVR.digestSectionId}" size='25' class="form-control" path="section[${sectionContent.index}].body" rows="25" />
            <form:errors path="section[${sectionContent.index}].body" cssClass="error" />
          </td>
          <form:hidden path="section[${sectionContent.index}] .digestSectionId" id="digestSectionId" />
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="record">
          </td>
        </tr>
```

As it is clear that I am using Spring MVC form elements so these are all binded to the model attribute `digesttemplate` which was created in my controller when we navigated to this view as

> **Controller** code

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/add"}, method={RequestMethod.GET})
public String add( Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("action", "save");
    model.addAttribute("digesttemplate", new DigestTemplate());
    return "digest-form";
}
```

If we already have sections in the database so it works absolutely fine and all the sections are rendered fine and when I submit the page after updating the existing section it gets reflected in my model attribute for saving controller as well as

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/save"}, method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("digesttemplate") DigestTemplate digest, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("action", "save");
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "digest-form";
    }

    DigestTemplate response = null; 
    try 
    {
        response = service.save(digest);    
    }
}
```

However when I create a new section using jQuery in the existing digest it doesn't get picked in the model attribute of the above controller.

> **jQuery Code for adding an element**

```
$("#add-row").click(function(){
  var id = $('#digestSectionId').val();
  id++;

  var markup = "<tr>";
  markup    += "  <td class='control-label'>";
  markup    += "    <input placeholder='Section Title'/>";
  markup    += "  </td>";
  markup    += "  <td>";
  markup    += "    <textarea id='html-body" + id + "' class='form-control' rows='25'/> <form:errors cssClass='error'  />";
  markup    += "  </td>";
  markup    += "  <td colspan='2'><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td>";
  markup    += "</tr>"; 

  $("#digestSectionId").val(id);
  $("table tbody").append(markup);
  $( document ).trigger( "page.ready" );
});
```

I have tried several things like cloning the element in jQuery as well but no luck. I will really appreciate a code example of achieving this.

Comment: HTML elements need a `name` attribute to be submitted to the server in the HTTP request. `<input placeholder='Section Title'/>` should be `<input name='section[...].title' placeholder='Section Title'/>` and `<textarea id='html-body...' class='form-control' rows='25'/>` should be `<textarea name='section[...].body' id='html-body...' class='form-control' rows='25'/>`. Use the browser console to monitor the HTTP request and see what values are submitted to get an idea of which fields are being submitted and which ones aren't. You will need to make sure that `...` is populated as a valid number.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked for me much appreciated